# Find the largest value in a column

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix like A below, although much larger in reality:

```
A =  2  100  250
     1  50   25
     0  600  700
     5  20   30
```

I want to find the row values based on the largest value in the **first** column. In my example above, I want to find the fourth row based on the column value "5" and also get its two other row values, 20 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the row indices for the maximum value of each column of matrix A like this:

```
[~, maxRowIndicesByColumn] = max(A,[],1);
```

Then to get the row with the largest value in the first column

```
A(maxRowIndicesByColumn(1),:)

ans =

 5    20    30
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) you can do it compact and quick:

```
result = A(A(:,1)==max(A(:,1)),:)
```

the inner part `A(:,1)==max(A(:,1))`, result in a vector of logicals (0 or 1) with each element corresponds to an element in the first column of `A`, and equals `1` if this element is the largest in the first column of `A` (i.e. it's `max(A(:,1))`). In your example it will be `[0;0;0;1]`.

Then, we extract from `A` each row that has `1` in our logical vector. Note, that if there are several values that are all equal `max(A(:,1))` then you'll get all corresponding rows.