# Matlab logical operation on array

Tags: matlab, matrix, logical-operators

My question should be fairly easy, but I can't get it to work.
I want to take from a matrix only the relevant rows by using logical operators and then storing those rows only.
I'm used to doing this with a for-loop in other languages, but in Matlab it should be faster to run this over the entire array or matrix at once.

This is an example of what I think should work, but all my similar attempts generate different errors, and I'm not sure what to do.

```
Mrelevant = Matrix(Matrix.no_refs > 100)
```

Edit: Matrix is actually a table with headers, I want to keep only the rows that fulfil certain requirements, like the value in the column with header 'no_refs' should be above 100.

I hope this is clear enough, thanks!

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: Apparently `Matrix` is not a matrix but a struct of some type. Please add code to create a sample `Matrix` and the output you expect for this data.

Comment: See here a close example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526311/find-the-largest-value-in-a-column/45526702#45526702

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you specified `Matrix` is a [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html), the answer is clear. You forgot an additional [colon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) index argument to include all variables for the given rows you are selecting:

```
Mrelevant = Matrix(Matrix.no_refs > 100, :);
```

This will give you a new table `Mrelevant` that includes only those rows from `Matrix` where the `no_refs` variable is greater than 100. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) for all of the ways to access data in a `table` by row and/or variable.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are showing here should work, though I do not know what the purpose of the `no_refs` might be. The correct syntax is:

```
Mrelevant = matrixName(matrixName > 100)
```

However, this will create a single column containing the values that meet the condition. For example,

```
testMatrix =
0.8147    0.0975    0.1576    0.1419    0.6557
0.9058    0.2785    0.9706    0.4218    0.0357
0.1270    0.5469    0.9572    0.9157    0.8491
0.9134    0.9575    0.4854    0.7922    0.9340
0.6324    0.9649    0.8003    0.9595    0.6787

relevant = testMatrix(testMatrix > .5)

relevant =
0.8147
0.9058
0.9134
0.6324
0.5469
0.9575
0.9649
0.9706
0.9572
0.8003
0.9157
0.7922
0.9595
0.6557
0.8491
0.9340
0.6787
```

However, when you say

> only the relevant rows by using logical operators and then storing
>   those rows

do you mean storing only rows where all elements in the row meet the condition? In that case, the syntax would be

```
 relevant = testMatrix
 % Delete all rows that don't meet the requirement
 relevant(any(relevant<=100, 2),:) = [];
```

This will simply erase any row containing values that don't meet your requirement.

Comment: I'm getting _Matrix index is out of range for deletion._ Any clue why that would be the case?

Comment: Could be because a particular matrix wasn't formed correctly. If you could post your command line or your script to the point that the error occurred, I can help debug it further.